# Python Regular Expression matching extra characters

Tags: python, regex

So I might be misunderstanding how this works, but I can't figure it out.
I have a string in python that has some text info and then contains a bunch of ip addresses in parenthesis followed by newline. So

```
"(192.168.2.101)\n(192.168.2.102)\n(192.168.2.103)\n..."
```

What I want to do is re to get a list of all the different host ID's (i.e. `101`, `102`, `103`).

This is just a simple example btw so non `re` methods probably won't work.

The issue I am having is that the list keeps giving me the ending parenthesis. That is, `['101)', '102)', ...]`

The expression I am using is

```
re.findall("192.168.2.(.*?)\n", str)
```

I am sure the issue will be obvious to people who are more knowledgeable about regular expressions. They drive me up the wall though. I have tried doing things like `[^)]` to exclude the end parenthesis and even just pull `0-9` but those all wind up returning `[]`.

Comment: If you only want digits, then do `(\d*)`.  Your `.*` is matching everything through the end of the line.  `.*` will match as much as it can.  And `.*?` is the same as `.*` -- the star will happily match nothing.

Comment: You should escape all the `.` characters that should be matched literally.

Comment: If you want the last number you can do `.*\.(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/lHEyfw/1

Comment: re.findall("192.168.2.(\d+)\\)\n", str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match a sequence of digits followed by `)\n`.

```
ips = "(192.168.2.101)\n(192.168.2.102)\n(192.168.2.103)\n..."
re.findall(r'\d+(?=\)\n)', ips)
```

`(?=\)\n)` is a lookahead that constrains the match to be followed by close paren and newline.